# how remove match items in arrayListOf kotlin

Tags: kotlin

```kotlin
    var a = arrayListOf<String>("hello","hello","lamine")
```

I need remove items match and  reprint it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to remove items that satisfy a particular condition, you just use [`removeAll`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/remove-all.html): `a.removeAll { str -> matches(str) }`.

If you're trying to remove duplicates, you'll need an added `Set`:

```
val deduped = a.toSet()
a.clear()
a.addAll(deduped)
```

or you can write

```
a = a.distinct()
```

if `a` is a `var`.

Comment: error removeAll: a.removeAll { str -> matches(str) }.

Comment: It [works for me](https://pl.kotl.in/7paqoeF3E).  Did you define `matches` appropriately?  Or substitute the definition for whatever "match" means for you?  What _does_ "match" even mean for you?

Comment: thank you it work

Comment: I'm guessing remove duplicates (remove strings that match other strings in the list) - total guess though, and guessing user requirements is always a bad idea :-)

Comment: You could also use _a.removeAll { str -> matches(str) }.distinct()_ to remove duplicates.